# Markov model for patients on a transplant waitlist?

Tags: probability, survival, conditional-probability, markov-chain-montecarlo

I am developing a Markov model in Treeage based upon survival data for individuals on a transplant waitlist (running first order monte carlo). Over the time horizon, individuals may either become ineligible for a transplant, receive a transplant, remain on the waitlist, or die. Death should generally be at the end, but for simplicity for now, lets say it is structured as the following:

Everyone begins on waitlist:
1st branch: remain eligible or become ineligible (terminal).
2nd branch: For those remaining eligible, did they die (terminal) or live.
3rd branch: For those who remain eligible and lived, did they get a transplant (terminal) or do they remain on the waitlist to begin the cycle again.

Let's say in the actual data this is what would have occurred in the first cycle:
600 began
27 were ineligible
10 died
15 received a transplant
and the remaining went back to the waitlist

I have tried running conditional probabilities in SAS (lifetest method act, each outcome separate, time is time of waitlist, censoring for other end points) as well as a competing risk model (cif at each cycle) for each outcome to determine transition probabilities by cycle, but both methods have not seemed to work (either over estimating or under estimating by cycle when validating against the actual counts in the data). I am not well versed when it comes to more complex models (for me anyways) such as this so I was wondering if anyone could provide some insight as to the proper method to calculate transition probabilities? Or if I'm looking this the wrong way or might need to consider a different type of model to analyze the problem. Any resources or guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This situation seems to amenable to the analysis of competing risks provided by the R [`survival` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=survival). You have a `waitlist` state, from which a transition is possible to exactly 1 of 3 terminal states: `ineligible`, `transplant`, and `death`. (As you note, one might further model a transition from `transplant` to `death` but we'll stay with the simple model.)

That is exactly what is depicted in the lower left of Figure 1 of the `survival` package's [multi-state vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/compete.pdf): a single starting state and 3 mutually exclusive terminal states. Section 2.2 of the vignette illustrates this type of competing risk analysis for 2 terminal states, using the `survfit()` function to describe the data, but that is easily extended to more terminal states.

> The result of a multi-state survfit is a matrix of probabilities with one row per time and one column per state.

That seems to be what you seek.* Note in particular this warning (page 8):

> A common mistake with competing risks is to use the Kaplan-Meier separately on each event type while treating other event types as censored.

That sounds like what you might have done. The vignette goes on to show the type of error that can result.

I'm not familiar with Treeage, but your use of the word "cycle" suggests that it implements a discrete-time Markov model. (Perhaps with fixed-in-time transition probabilities?) In contrast, continuous-time modeling with the `survival` package allows for arbitrary changes in the hazards of each transition over time since entry into the `waitlist` state. Unless there is a compelling reason to do otherwise, it seems that the flexibility provided by the tools in the `survival` package are a better choice for your application.

---

*If you wish, you can further model transition hazards as functions of covariates with the `coxph()` function.